# Displaying Django forms in webpage

Tags: python, html, django

I've been trying for a few hours to get a Django form to display on a web page, but I seem to missing something. There's a few posts already on similar issues, but I'm sure I've followed them through and I'm still having the same issue. Really appreciate it if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong.

**The Problem**

When my form loads on web page, it only shows the submit button. The rest of the form - i.e. the input is listed as being hidden.

**The Goal**

My goal is to have this simple form displayed on the webpage then I'll start playing with ModelForms.

Here's my code:
forms.py

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    field1 = forms.CharField('Your name', max_length=100)
```

models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False, null=False)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views import generic
import stock_analysis.yahooFinance

from .models import Choice, Question
from .forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):
# if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

Template index.html

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I can put the rest of the HTML in if required, but it's just a normal form to see if I was doing something really silly.

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: what seems to be the problem? Please elaborate and post the errors, as well as `urls.py`. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Which view are you using here, `get_name` or `IndexView`? The form exists in the first, but not the second. What do your URLs look like?

Comment: I'm using the get_name view, I included the IndexView in case it was causing errors.

Comment: What do you mean by "lists as being hidden"? Do the form fields become `<input type="hidden">`? Or do they have `visibility: hidden` CSS property?

Comment: the first one <input type="hidden">

Comment: is your template name index.html or name.html?

Comment: Do you have any scripts on your page? Maybe they are changing inputs' type to hidden? Try removing all the scripts and see what happens

Comment: Hang on though, you've said the template is index.html, but your view is rendering name.html. Which is it?